# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope in android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, xml-parsing, android-ksoap2

I already added ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-RC.4-jar-with-dependencies in libs folder then also i have show bellow error when i run app using android studio.

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope

please give me solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the jar file and clean the project then add the library file in your libs folder and right click the jar file then click the Add as Library.
finally rebuild the project and run it :-)